# Where is a good place to start programming GUIs for windows?

Tags: winapi, qt, mfc

I have experience writing console and network client/server applications in C and C++, but I know next to nothing about using the win32 visual API, MFC, Qt, wxWidgets, etc.  Where is a good place to start, and what method should I specialize in, so as to be future ready and robust?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This is a rather broad question, as programming GUI applications in Windows can be done in so many ways.

There are two main parts to developing any GUI app: the **language** and the **API/framework**. Considering you're interested in learning to build Windows GUI apps, the language isn't really a point of focus for you. Hence, you should pick a language you already know and work with a framework or API that can be harnessed by your chosen language.

If you want to use C you're pretty much restricted to dealing with the Win32 API yourself, in which case reading [Petzold](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/157231995X) or [Richter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735624240) would be great places to start. The Win32 API can be quite daunting, but it's well worth the effort to learn (imho). There are plenty of tutorials on Win32 on the web, and there's always [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/), with a complete reference/guide to the Win32 API. Make sure you cover not just the API, but other areas such as resources/dialogs as they are building blocks for your Win32 application.

If you want to use C++ you have all of the options that you have when using C plus a few others. I'd recommend going with the Win32 API directly, and then moving on to a known framework such as MFC, Qt, wxWindows or GTK so that you can spend less time working with boilerplate code and instead focus on writing your application logic. The last 3 options I just listed have the added benefit of being cross-platform, so you don't have to worry too much about platform-specific issues. Given that you said you want to work with Windows, I'll assume you're keen to focus on that rather than cross-platform -- so go with MFC, but spend some time with the Win32 API first to get familiar with some of the concepts.

When dealing with MFC and the Win32 API, it's a good idea to try and get a solid understanding of the terminology prior to writing code. For example, you need to understand what the [message pump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_loop_in_Microsoft_Windows) is, and how it works. You need to know about concepts such as "[owner-drawn](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/buttons/nativewin32xpthemes.aspx) controls", and [subclassing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997565.aspx). When you understand these things (and more), you'll find it easier to work with MFC because it uses similar terminology in its class interfaces (eg. you need to know what "translate messages" means before you can understand how and when to use [PreTranslateMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkbhxcs2(VS.80).aspx)).

You could also use Managed C++ to write .NET GUI applications, but I've read in a few places that Managed C++ wasn't really intended to be used in this manner. Instead it should be used as a gateway between native/unmanaged code and managed code. If you're using .NET it's best to use a .NET language such as VB.NET or C# to build your GUIs.

So if you *are* going to use .NET, you currently have the choice of the [WinForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa497342.aspx) library, or [WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation). I personally feel that you'd be wasting time learning to build WinForms applications given that WPF is designed to replace it. Over time WPF will become more prevelant and Winforms will most likely die off. WPF has a much richer API set, and doesn't suffer from many of the limitations that Winforms does. If you do choose this route, however, you'll no doubt have to learn [XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752059.aspx), which is a markup language that drives WPF applications. This technology is coming of age, and there are many great places to learn about it. First, there are sites such as [LearnWPF](http://learnwpf.com/), and [DrWPF](http://www.drwpf.com/) which have some really great articles. Secondly, there are [plenty](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321374479) of [quality](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596510373) [books](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672328917) on the [topic](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590599551).

So, to sum up, once you've picked your language and tech, the path is actually quite easy. Just pick up a book or two, read some blogs, get into some code samples.. and most importantly ... write code. Keep writing, keep making mistakes, and keep learning from them.

As a final note...

> In other words, Silverlight. If you don't want to go the MS route you might give Adobe's Flash/Flex a look see. Both Silverlight and Flash/Flex build RIA's. Which I think is where we are headed. They days of Office like apps are numbered

I don't agree at all. Silverlight is not the same as WPF. Silverlight is web-specific, and only has a subset of WPF's features. Given that the question asks for Windows GUI apps, Flash/Flex Rich Internet Apps are not really a fitting suggestion. I also don't agree that the days of Rich Client Applications (such as office) are numbered at all.

I hope that helps. Good luck :)

Comment: If you want to use the Win32 API from C++, there's also WTL. See http://wtl.sourceforge.net/

Comment: +1 for Petzold and Ritcher.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if I'd call it a good place to start, but if you want to be future ready, take a look at the [windows presentation foundation](http://windowsclient.net/) which is built entirely for the purpose of programming GUI's for windows

Answer (score 3):

My first experience writing simple GUI applications for Windows was with C# and Visual Studio.  The GUI-building interface is a simple drag and drop deal that generates skeleton methods based on potential user actions.  I only did fairly basic programming with this, but I imagine it would be an excellent place to start to learn the basics and extend into the more advanced capabilities as you go.

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of online Win32 tutorials:

http://www.zeusedit.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1218

There are plenty of compilers to choose from:

http://www.zeusedit.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=238

I would also recommend getting the **Borland Win32 SDK** documentation in WinHelp file format:

http://www.zeusedit.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=7

It only covers the bare basics of the Win32, but when starting, this can be helpful as it is less daunting and less bloated than the MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

I'd never go down the Silverlight, Flash/Flex or any similar route. It does look nice, but the main problem is that the code of the engine that runs it is completely closed-box and controlled by a single company. Take, for example 64bit versions of both of those. If some new platform emerges, you won't be able to migrate your existing code to it.

Comment: Closed box and single company aren't issues at all. Regardless of the box you work in you still run the risk of never being able to port your code to it. Unjustified FUD is not an argument for avoiding Silverlight or Flash.

Answer (score 0):

For business apps, Windows Forms is very mature. It provides a gentle path from auto-generating a lot for you into allowing fine-grained control and rolling your own.  There are tons of high-quality third party controls and a large body of examples, docs, etc out there. It's hard to run into a problem that someone else hasn't solved. I highly recommend acquiring some background Win32 knowledge (e.g. [Petzold](http://www.charlespetzold.com/pw5/index.html)) as the WinForms framework lives on top of it.

I have no WPF experience, but from the sample apps I've seen it looks like a good choice for apps whose interfaces would benefit from more graphical metaphors. So if you're doing a banking app, probably not worth the extra design overhead. But if you're doing, say, a warehouse management app it could be improved by dropping pretty boxes into pretty bins.

@StephenCox: wrong answer to the wrong question. OP is asking about desktop client apps, and moreover, WPF != Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple starting point to get your head around the "event-driven" nature basically all frameworks are created around look at [FLTK](http://www.fltk.org).

Here are some quick starting videos [Link](http://seriss.com/people/erco/fltk-videos/)

For professional use I'd recommend Qt, expensive but often worth it in commercial situations.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already familiar with C and C++ I would recommend learning how to write a simple Windows GUI app using Charles Petzold's book.  It will give you the fundamental understanding of how Windows works.  It's good to understand that most everything that you see is a window (a button is a window for example) and that these windows respond to messages.  I wouldnt' spend a lot of time on this though and you don't necessarily need to do this first if you are going to chose WPF.  I just think it's good to have a basic understanding of this.

There was a good podcast recently on .Net Rocks called ["Kate Gregory Develops in C++ for Vista!"](http://www.dotnetrocks.com/default.aspx?showNum=363) on there she recommends that someone starting out now should not use/learn MFC (even though it has been recently updated).

As far as getting ready for the future you need to learn WPF, but it isn't complete yet, so depending on the kinds of client side apps you want to create, you will probably need to learn WinForms.  The majority of people aren't using WPF yet, so it's a good time to start learning.  I think you will find it easier using C# to learn it instead of doing managed code with C++.

Answer (score 0):

Get your basics right first. Best tutorial I've found is: http://winprog.org/tutorial/start.html

After that, although the homepage is hatefully distasteful, the tutorial pages are good in content and aesthetics: http://www.tenouk.com/cplusmfcdotnet.html

Then of course there's [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751972%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).